# Is it possible to rotate the canvas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Can the canvas be rotated so north is pointing in some other direction than defined by the projection? This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54060/can-qgis-1-8-0-mac-rotate-the-entire-view-of-a-project) answers with respect to the composer, but not the canvas. There is a related 5 year old entry in the bug tracking database that's closed as unnecessary. Is that the current status, or is there a way to rotate the canvas in the newer versions?

Creating a new projection is really not the answer

Comment: If you want to play with rotating canvas with open source GIS you can do it with OpenEV that can be installed with OSGeo4W installer.

Comment: I have qgis projects with dozens of layers and styling for each layer. This would not work in OpenEV.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Map canvas rotation is being added as a feature to QGIS 2.8.
Here's a video posted by Faunalia of the feature.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TN3toqcyks

Comment: But labels are disappearing during rotation! How to fix that?

Answer (score 22):

In QGIS at bottom right corner, there is an option called 'Rotation'.

There you can rotate your canvas (or extent of view) by any angle.

Answer (score 2):

If creating new projection is not the answer then I am not aware about any direct way.

From my point of view if QGIS starts with dynamic rotation it should be taken directly to another level - 3D (2.5) like Arscene/Google Earth/Discover 3D to name few approaches of different software solutions...

There is some way through plugin GLOBE:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDDe-sVogNU

GRASS (NVIZ):

http://linfiniti.com/2010/12/3d-visualisation-and-dem-creation-in-qgis-with-the-grass-plugin/

And export plugin:

http://anitagraser.com/2014/03/15/3d-viz-with-qgis-three-js/